# Prove that ${|a-b|}^r\leq |a^r-b^r|$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Suppose that $a,b\geq 0$ and Let $r\geq 1$ ($r$ is real). Prove that

$${|a-b|}^r\leq |a^r-b^r|$$

What is the name of this inequality? Is it  a special case from a famous inequality ?

I am looking for different simple proofs for it.

Comment: does |a-b| means modulus function here?

Comment: Yes in real case absolute value. Of Course , $a$ & $b$ are real numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no loss in assuming that $a\ge b$. If we write $c=a-b$ then the
inequality becomes
$$(b+c)^r\ge b^r+c^r$$
for $b$, $c\ge0$. Actually we might as well assume $b$, $c>0$. It we set
$$t=b/(b+c)$$ the inequality becomes
$$1\ge t^r+(1-t)^r$$
for $0<t<1$. The function of $t$ on the right is convex for $0\le t\le1$
so its graph on this interval is on or below the line $f(t)=1$.